# Sharing computer audio over Zoom or MS Teams

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, zoom-meeting

I am unable to share my computer audio through an online meeting -- I have tested with both Zoom and Microsoft teams and the result is the same.  Using Ubuntu 20.04, Zoom 5.4.57450.1220 installed as a Snap.

I suspect the mechanisms are different, so taking [Zoom](https://zoom.us/) as the example (since everyone can try it for free), I can share the screen with no problems.  When I do so, I check the "Share Computer Sound" box.  However the only audio the participants can hear is that picked up by the laptop microphone. If I play the sound loud enough of course the microphone picks it up, but I don't believe this is what the "share computer sound" box is meant to do.

When supposedly sharing sound, if I open [pavucontrol](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pavucontrol) and look at the `Recording` tab, the only entry is "ZOOM VoiceEngine: recStream *from*" and it is set to "sof-hda-dsp Digital Microphone" which is my laptop's built-in microphone.  That appears to me to be clearly wrong -- I believe it can't possibly hope to get the computer audio that way.  The source drop-down has numerous options; conceivably "Monitor of sof-hda-dsp Speaker and Headphones" could be what I want* but I cannot change the setting -- attempting to change the selected source has no effect.  That is, it doesn't even change the displayed text, let alone fix the problem.

Zoom's own microphone settings allow the input to be changed, but only to "real" microphones, not to "monitor of..." sources.

I think this is a clear bug -- it doesn't do what it clearly should (i.e. share the computer audio).

I have two questions:

1. Whose bug is it? To whom should I report it? (First instinct is Zoom, but Microsoft Teams is broken in the same way.)
2. Is there a workaround I can use?

The solution in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558149/play-audio-output-as-input-to-zoom) (mute, share, unmute) did not have any effect.

---

*but I suspect it's not -- it would include the received audio from other participants, and hence would feed back

Answer (score 0):

On my system,  I've got skype open and am looking at the Recording tab of pavucontrol. The options on the right are:

- Monitor of Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo
- Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo
- H2 Stereo

That last one is my external microphone.

I turned on spotify playing music and gone back to pavucontrol. Looking at the `Input Devices` tab, I can see that `Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo` is set to use the port `Internal Microphone`. I've turned the slider for that down to silence. I've also turned down my H2 to silence.  Looking, finally, at `Monitor of Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo`, it's level meter matches what's coming from spotify. If I turn off spotify and make noise near any of my microphones, the meter doesn't show anything.  Therefore, I feel confident it's the audio signal from spotify.

Going to the `Recording` tab on pavucontrol, I can see skype listed.  On the right hand side, I can see the options listed at the top. All of them are now turned down in the `Input Devices` tab, aside from `Monitor of Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo`.  If I play spotify again, that selection is the only one that shows audio on the meter.

If your system is doing something different, that's a problem with Pulseaudio.  This blog post about using Jack and pulse together may show you a work-around: https://www.fossbox.org.uk/?p=240

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I don't think it addresses the issue. I too can find a source in pavucontrol which contains the system audio. The (first) problem is that I can't select it as a source for the recording. (The second problem, I suspect, would be that if I could, it would contain received audio from other participants -> feedback).

Answer (score 0):

I tested the solution from the stackexchange website which you have mentioned to share my video, and it works flawlessly with Ubuntu 18.04 and Zoom 5.4.9.

Here are some tips to make it works:

1. As described in the stackexchange website, make sure that you have opened the application to play your audio or video (in my case, I use Videos in Ubuntu) **before sharing your screen**. This step is necessary so that Zoom can detect the application to play your audio or video.
2. When you are about to share your screen, do not forget to click the 'Share computer sound'
3. Do not click the 'Optimize screen sharing for video clip' if your want to share your video with high resolutions.